# Drag multiple files

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop, listbox

I have a ListBox with a list of filepaths, which has the property `SelectionMode` set to `MultiExtended`. Thus, I can select many items from this list.

Now, I want to Drag and Drop files starting from those paths in the destination folder where I drop them.

My code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // populate the FileList
    // i.e. FileList.Items.Add("d:/Samples/file-00" + i + ".wav");

    this.FileList.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(FileList_MouseDown);
    this.FileList.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(FileList_DragOver);
}

void FileList_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

void FileList_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> filesToDrag = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in FileList.SelectedItems)
    {
        filesToDrag.Add(item.ToString().Trim());
    }

    this.FileList.DoDragDrop(new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, 
                             filesToDrag.ToArray()), DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```

it works perfect if I select and drop 1 single line/file from the ListBox to the destination folder.

Instead, if I do a multiple selection and I try to drag and drop, it can just select that one line where I start to drag. Seems that `MouseDown` prevent this?

How would you fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this with a `ListBox` seems to be ridiculously hard. Actually I haven't found a solution at all..

Use a `ListView` instead! It is easy as pie, using the `ItemDrag` event and is a **much better** control anyway.. I can't count how often I had to change from a 'cheap' `ListBox` to `ListView` because I needed this or that 'little' extra..

Here is your code moved to a `ItemDrag`:

```
private void listView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> filesToDrag = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in listView1.SelectedItems)
    {
        filesToDrag.Add(item.ToString().Trim());
    }

    this.listView1.DoDragDrop(new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop,
                                filesToDrag.ToArray()), DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```

Note that this only solves the problem of the MouseDown changing the selection. It is in itself not a guarantuee that the actual copying will work.

I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23207/Drag-and-Drop-to-Windows-Folder-C) interesting article that proposes a solution. Maybe you don't need it, as you have said that you got copying one file already working..

Comment: Can you place to me an example of ListView and ItemDrag?

Comment: I have added the code but can't get it to do any actual copying :-(

Answer (score 0):

Yeah...I don't think there's a good way around that problem.  When you click again to initiate the drag it will toggle that item.  We don't know that the user actually wants to do a drag until the mouse is **held down and moved**.

One potential solution is to initiate the drag/drop from something else, just somehow make it really clear that is what the user should drag.  Here I'm using a Label instead of the ListBox:

```
    void label1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            List<string> filesToDrag = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in FileList.SelectedItems)
            {
                filesToDrag.Add(item.ToString().Trim());
            }
            if (filesToDrag.Count > 0)
            {
                this.FileList.DoDragDrop(new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop,
                                     filesToDrag.ToArray()), DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select Files First!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be picky about the mouse down and mouse move activities.  When it is within the graphics rectangle of your listbox, you'll want normal behavior.  When it is outside the bounds of this rectangle, you'll want drag/drop functionality.  You can try the pseudo code below:

```
MouseDown(sender, e)
{
    var x = <your sender as control>.ItemFromPoint(.....)
    this.mouseLocation = x == null ? x : e.Location;
}

MouseMove(sender, e)
{
    if control rectangle doesn't contain the current location then
        <your sender as control>.Capture = false
        DoDragDrop
}
```